# Camel - CSV Headers setting not working

Tags: csv, apache-camel

I have CSV files without headers. Since I'm using 'useMaps' I want to specify the headers dynamically. If I set headers statically and then use in route it works fine as below Approach 1 -

```
@Component
public class BulkActionRoutes extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat(",");
        csv.setUseMaps(true);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("DeviceName");
        list.add("Brand");
        list.add("status");
        list.add("type");
        list.add("features_c");
        list.add("battery_c");
        list.add("colors");
        csv.setHeader(list);

        from("direct:bulkImport")
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .unmarshal(csv)
        .split(body()).streaming()
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                GenericObjectModel model = null;
                HashMap<String, String> csvRecord = (HashMap<String, String>)exchange.getIn().getBody();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, if the list is passed via Camel headers as below then it does not work Approach 2 -

```
@Component
public class BulkActionRoutes extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat(",");
        csv.setUseMaps(true);

        from("direct:bulkImport")
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                ArrayList<String> fileHeaders = (ArrayList<String>)headers.get(Constants.FILE_HEADER_LIST);
                if (fileHeaders != null && fileHeaders.size() > 0) {
                    csv.setHeader(fileHeaders);
                }
            }
        })
        .unmarshal(csv)
        .split(body()).streaming()
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                GenericObjectModel model = null;
                HashMap<String, String> csvRecord = (HashMap<String, String>)exchange.getIn().getBody();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What could be missing in the Approach 2?

Answer (score 0):

The big difference between approach 1 and 2 is the scope.

In approach 1 you fully configure the CSV data format. This is **all done when the Camel Context is created**, since the data format is shared within the Camel Context. When messages are processed, it is the **same config for all messages**.

In approach 2 you just configure the basics globally. The header **configuration is within the route** and therefore **can change for every single message**. Every message would overwrite the header configuration of the context-global data format instance.

Without being sure about this, I guess that it is **not possible to change a context-global DataFormat inside the routes**.

What would you expect (just for example) when messages are processed in parallel? They would overwrite the header config against each other.

As an alternative, you could use a POJO where you can do your dynamic marshal / unmarshal from Java code.

Comment: The CVS headers will vary from file to file. So I need an option to set the header per file once before the 'unmarshal'. This is a generic route that will be called within another route.

Comment: Well then you probably cannot use Camel to marshal and unmarshal. You can use, as I wrote, a POJO and Java code with whatever CSV lib suits your need to handle the complete unmarshal for a message. Then you call the bean from your route and remove the whole CSV stuff from it.